# Final touches on my Java code?

Tags: java

I'm more than 90 percent done with my code... Wanna add a few things but I've got no idea how to proceed.

This is my code so far... I have other classes as well, and I'm calling them in this code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SensorStatsApp extends Sensor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        HumiditySensor hSensor = new HumiditySensor();
        int sChoice = -2;               
        int hChoice = -2;               
        int seasonTemp = -2;              
        int humidityTemp = -2;        
        int iterations = -2;   

        while(true)
        {

        try {
            System.out.println("What season would you like to simulate?");
            System.out.println(" 1. Winter \n 2. Spring \n 3. Summer \n 4. Fall \n 5. Random \n 6. EXIT");
            System.out.print("Selection: ");
            sChoice = sc.nextInt();             // gathers user input for which season to simulate
            System.out.println();               // adds a break from the previous question

            if(sChoice == 6){   
                System.exit(0); // exits the program 
            }

                System.out.println("What humidity would you like to simulate?");
                System.out.println(" 1. Full Range \n 2. Low Humidity \n 3. High Humidity \n 4. Random \n 5. EXIT");
                System.out.print("Selection: ");
                hChoice = sc.nextInt();             // gathers user input for humidity to simulate
                System.out.println();               // adds a break from previous question

            if(hChoice == 5){
                System.exit(0); // exits the program 
            }

            System.out.print("Input number of simulations: ");
                iterations = sc.nextInt();  // gathers user input for number of iterations
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {     // if user inputed non numeric characters
            System.out.println(e + " - Error: expecting a number for input");
            return; // exits the program
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
            try {
                seasonTemp = seasonToSimulate(sChoice);      // sends the sChoice int to be converted
                humidityTemp = humidityToSimulate(hChoice);  // sends the sChoice int to be converted and processed
                display(seasonTemp, humidityTemp, i);        // displays the current iteration of information
            }
            catch(IOException e){

                System.out.println(e + " - Error: user input");   // lets the user know why their sChoice failed.
                return;     // doesn't return anything cause the return type is void. This just ends the program.
            }
        }
    }
}
    public static void display(int sTemp, int hTemp, int iteration){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(++iteration + " Simulations:");   
        System.out.println("Season Temperature:   " + sTemp);
        System.out.println("Humidity Temperature: " + hTemp);
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static int humidityToSimulate(int choice) throws IOException {

        int temp = -2;
        HumiditySensor hSensor = new HumiditySensor();

        Boolean done = false;   // if random another iteration through switch is needed

        while(!done){ // if the user decides to use random then done != true so I can iterate one more time in the switch statement
          switch(choice){      // sChoice is the season in terms of an int

            case 1:   {     // full range, if choice is 1 it falls into this case and breaks at the statement break; (ends the current switch)
                temp = hSensor.getHumidity();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 2:   {    // low humidity, if choice is 2 it falls into this case.
                temp = hSensor.getLowHumidity();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 3:   {      // high humidity
                temp = hSensor.getHighHumidity();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 4:   {      // random
                choice = (int) Math.random() * 3; // random times (3) for 3 humidity types
                if(choice == 0) choice++;  // 0 is a possibility but not an option
                break;
            }
            case 5:  {       // exit
                temp = -1;       // lets the calling function know it's done
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new IOException(); // user gave improper option
            }       
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
    public static int seasonToSimulate(int choice) throws IOException {
        int temp = -1;
        TemperatureSensor tSensor = new TemperatureSensor();
        Boolean done = false;   // if random through switch is needed

        while(!done){
            switch(choice) {      
            case 1: {               // winter
                temp = tSensor.getWinterTemp();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 2: {              // spring
                temp = tSensor.getSpringTemp();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 3: {             // summer
                temp = tSensor.getSummerTemp();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 4: {        // fall
                temp = tSensor.getFallTemp();
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            case 5:  {       // random
                choice = (int) Math.random() * 4;// random *(4) for 4seasons
                if(choice == 0) choice++;// 0 is a possibility not an option
                break;
            }
            case 6:  {     // exit
                temp = -1;       // lets the calling function know it's done
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new IOException(); // user gave improper option
            }       
        }
    }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

How would I do the following in my program?
 Each iteration should display the readings being generated for each temperature and humidity. At the end your program should display a summary of the simulation as follows:

```
Season: _________ (if random, then display Random:Summer for example)

1-  First temperature generated
2-  Last temperature generated
3-  Lowest temperature generated
4-  Highest temperature generated
5-  Total sum of all temperatures generated
6-  Average for the season

Humidity Type: _________ (if random, then display Random:Full for example)
1-  First humidity reading generated
2-  Last humidity reading generated
3-  Lowest humidity reading generated
4-  Highest humidity reading generated
5-  Total sum of all humidity readings generated
6-  Average humidity reading
```

Comment: You should make your Q more specific i.e. about the parts you haven't implemented and what you have tried to do to implement those parts rather than dump everything and ask us to work it out for you.

Comment: I guess I should have... I have MOST of this DONE... WOO!

The only things I'm missing is the fact that I can't get the lowest and highest temps and humidity to show up.

Comment: this is what I implemented in my code to try and do so:

 if(seasonTemp > highSeasonTemp)
     highSeasonTemp = seasonTemp;
     if(seasonTemp < lowSeasonTemp)
      lowSeasonTemp = seasonTemp;


     if(lastSeasonTemp > highSeasonTemp)
      highSeasonTemp = lastSeasonTemp;
     if(lastSeasonTemp < lowSeasonTemp)
      lowSeasonTemp = lastSeasonTemp;

Comment: oooo it came out weird looking... but thats what i tried.